# JavaScript or React - database security in single-page website

Tags: javascript, html, database, reactjs, contact-form

**Welcome stackoverflow community.**

I'm doing small project, simple single-page website. It will also contain contact form which takes user to different page. I decided to create a database since on website I will do few responsive features ie. booking calendar where occupied dates won't be available. I wrote all my projects in vanilla js so far. I'm wondering that adding react to this project will be overkill.

I did research and know roughly cons and props for using it but I couldn't find answer if react gives you some extra safety features comparing to using vanilla js over attacks to website, and if yes, does it makes sense to write whole project in react just for those features?

Many thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be rewriting your app in react just for security. If you have any sensitive information. You should be keeping it on the server and not on the front-end.

For a small project. Vanilla JS can be enough. React is just for helping you manage and create UI components. It will not give you any extra security as it is still javascript in the end.